# Validation for bloodgroup and date of birth in android

Tags: android

Hai I am very new to android development. I am trying to put validation for blood group(AB+ OR AB- OR A+ OR A- OR B+ OR B- OR O+ OR O-) and data of birth(DD/MM/YYY) in my application. How to write a code exctly for validation of blood group and date of birth. Below is my code;

```
Main activity:-

    package com.example.uniqval.registration;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button mSubmit;
        private Button mCancel;
        private EditText mname;
        private EditText dob;
        private EditText mUsername;
        private EditText mPassword;
        private EditText mEmail;
        private EditText mphone;
        private EditText maddress;
        private EditText mbloodgroup;
        private EditText memergencycontactno1;
        private EditText memergencycontactno2;

    //    private Spinner mGender;
    //    private String Gen;

        protected DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    0
        }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
            mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

            mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

            mname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.efname);
            dob = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);

            mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reuname);
            mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repass);
            mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eemail);
            mphone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pphoneno);
            maddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.paddress);
            mbloodgroup=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pbldgrp);
            memergencycontactno1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pemc1);
            memergencycontactno2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pemc2);

            //     mGender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            // Spinner method to read the on selected value
          /*  ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] {
                    new State("Male"),
                    new State("Female")});
            mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.cancel:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registration cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.submit:

                    if(!validateName())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateDOB())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateUserName())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validatePassword())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateEmail())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validatePhoneNumber())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateAddress())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateBloodGr())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateContact1())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!validateContact2())
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    addEntry(mname.getText().toString(), dob.getText().toString(), mUsername.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString(),
                            mEmail.getText().toString(), mphone.getText().toString(),maddress.getText().toString(),mbloodgroup.getText().toString(),
                            memergencycontactno1.getText().toString(),memergencycontactno2.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registration sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    //           String fname = mname.getText().toString();
                    /*String dofb = dob.getText().toString();

                    String uname = mUsername.getText().toString();
                    String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();
                    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                    String PhoneNo = mphone.getText().toString();
                    String Address=maddress.getText().toString();
                    String BloodGroup=mbloodgroup.getText().toString();
                    String EmergencyContactNo1=memergencycontactno1.getText().toString();
                    String EmergencyContactNo2=memergencycontactno2.getText().toString();
    */
                  /*  boolean invalid = false;

                    if (fname.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (dofb.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Lastname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (uname.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (pass.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (email.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Email ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (PhoneNo.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else if (Address.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (BloodGroup.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your BloodGroup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (EmergencyContactNo1.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your EmergencyContactNo1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (EmergencyContactNo2.equals("")) {
                        invalid = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your EmergencyContactNo2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (invalid == false) {*/

                    //finish();
               /*     }

                    break;*/

            }

        }
        private boolean validateName() {
            if (mname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    mname.setError("Enter Your Name");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}
                requestFocus(mname);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private boolean validateDOB() {
            if (dob.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    dob.setError("Enter Your Date of Birth");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}
                requestFocus(dob);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private boolean validateUserName() {
            if (mUsername.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    mUsername.setError("Enter User Name");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}
                requestFocus(mUsername);
                return false;
            }
            return true;

    }

    private boolean validateAddress() {
        if (maddress.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                maddress.setError("Enter Address");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(maddress);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateContact1() {
        if (memergencycontactno1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                memergencycontactno1.setError("Enter Contact Number");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(memergencycontactno1);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateContact2() {
        if (memergencycontactno2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                memergencycontactno2.setError("Enter Contact Number");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(memergencycontactno2);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateBloodGr() {
        if (mbloodgroup.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                mbloodgroup.setError("Enter Your Blood group");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(mbloodgroup);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
        if (mphone.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                mphone.setError("Enter Your phone number");
                if (mphone.length()!=10)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your valid 10 digit phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(mphone);
            return false;
        }

            return true;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword() {
        if (mPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                mPassword.setError("Enter Your Password");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            requestFocus(mPassword);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateEmail() {
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
            try {
                mEmail.setError("Invalid email id");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(mEmail);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    private boolean validatergencycontactno1() {
        if (mphone.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                memergencycontactno1.setError("Enter Your phone number");
                if (memergencycontactno1.length()!=10)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your valid 10 digit emergencycontactno1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(mphone);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    private boolean validatebloodgroup(){

        return true;
    }
    private boolean validatergencycontactno2() {
        if (mphone.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                memergencycontactno2.setError("Enter Your phone number");
                if (memergencycontactno2.length()!=10)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your valid 10 digit emergencycontactno2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
            requestFocus(mphone);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        DB.close();
    }



    private void addEntry(String name, String dob, String uname, String pass, String email, String phoneno, String addr,
                          String bloodgr, String contact1, String contact2)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("dob", dob);
        values.put("username", uname);
        values.put("password", pass);
        values.put("email", email);
        values.put("phoneno", phoneno);
        values.put("address", addr);
        values.put("bloodgroup", bloodgr);
        values.put("econtact1", contact1);
        values.put("econtact2", contact2);

        try
        {
            db.insert(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your details submitted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

content_main.xml:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.uniqval.registration.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/til"><EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/efname"
                android:hint="Name"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/dob"
                    android:hint="Date of Birth"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/reuname"
                    android:hint="Username"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/repass"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/eemail"
                    android:hint="Email"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/pphoneno"
                    android:hint="Phone No"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/paddress"
                    android:hint="Address"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/pbldgrp"
                    android:hint="Blood Group"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/pemc1"
                    android:hint="Emergency Contact No1"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/pemc2"
                    android:hint="Emergency Contact No2"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
activity+_main.xml:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.uniqval.registration.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:weightSum="2" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/round" android:id="@+id/submit" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Submit"/>



     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/round" android:id="@+id/cancel" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submit"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Spinner or radio button group. Letting user enter and then validate blood group is kinda tedious. Also you can use datepicker for date of birth, that way you will not need to validate.

Answer (score 0):

In xml :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_blood_group"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/msg_blood_group"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:digits="aboABO+-"/>
```

In validation code :

```
public static boolean isBloodGroupValid(String bloodGroup, Context context){
        if(bloodGroup != null) {
            String[] bloodGroups = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.blood_groups);
            int len = bloodGroups.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(bloodGroup.equalsIgnoreCase(bloodGroups[i]))
                    return true;
            }
        }return false;
    }
```

In strings.xml

```
<string-array name="blood_groups">
        <item>O+</item>
        <item>O-</item>
        <item>A+</item>
        <item>A-</item>
        <item>B+</item>
        <item>B-</item>
        <item>AB+</item>
        <item>AB-</item>
    </string-array>
```

Alternatively, you can also define a spinner with pre-populated items from the array, so that no one can enter invalid values.

Example to check if age is between 18 to 24 yrs:

```
public static boolean isDOBInRange(String dateStr) {
        try {
            Calendar calMin = Calendar.getInstance();
            calMin.add(Calendar.YEAR, -Constants.MAX_AGE_LIMIT); //24
            Date dateStart = calMin.getTime();

            Calendar calMax = Calendar.getInstance();
            calMax.add(Calendar.YEAR, -Constants.MIN_AGE_LIMIT); //18
            Date dateEnd = calMax.getTime();

            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date date = format.parse(dateStr);

            if (date != null && dateStart != null && dateEnd != null) {
                if (date.after(dateStart) && date.before(dateEnd)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Edit your date format & age limits accordingly.